# jsoup is not getting some html tags from a webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get a SELECT node from a webpage using JSOUP. The problem that I have is that I just get the first OPTION node inside the SELECT node. When I checked the html source code for the above-mentioned webpage, I see that there are 9 OPTION nodes inside the SELECT node. This is the java code I am using:

```
Document doc;
Elements stops; 
try {
  doc = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/scriptCheck.asp?
         script=yes&CurrentPage=/transit/mobile/schedules.asp?route=3")
    .userAgent(" Mozilla/5.0")
    .timeout(30000)
    .get();

stops = doc.getElementsByTag("select");

for (Element option : stops) {
    System.out.print(option.text());
}

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just go directly to the webpage noted, you do get a select element with a single option  ("-").  In order to get all of the options, you need to go back to `http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp?route=3` and click "View Schedule".  I'm guessing that in order to get this to work, you will first have to send that POST request in order to get the select will all of the options.